# Executing a list of objects in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a list of object that I want to execute at the same time.

```
private List<Calculate_Data> ListOfDataToCalculate = new List<Calculate_Data>();
```

I have a method that loops through the list of as and call `StartCalculate()` follow:

```
public async void StartCalculating()
{
    foreach (var alldata in ListOfDataToCalculate )
    {
       alldata.StartCalculate();     
    }
}
```

Is there a way to blast them all and make them `alldata.StartCalculate()` in parallel instead of in sequence?
I know that we can use

```
var calculatetask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    alldata.StartCalculate();   
});
```

But is there to do them all at the same time? Some objects are longer to execute and some are faster.  The ending does not matter.  What's important is doing all at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: If it were a `List<Task>`, you could do `Task.WaitAll(taskList)`. Actually if you start a task and add it to a list of tasks inside the loop, you can do just that.

Comment: `Task.Run` returns before the task is completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-foreach-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-action((-0)))):

```
Parallel.ForEach(ListOfDataToCalculate, alldata =>
{
    alldata.StartCalculate(); 
});
```

Comment: What does `.StartCalculate()` do? Could you be writing to the same data in parallel?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue where one of my code count increments with n++; therefore looping infinitely.